# What is wrong with my Spec?

Tags: grails, spock

So, I have this pretty simple Spec below. I have a class that is not a controller or service or anything like that. It's a Job class. It depends on two services: updateService and directoryTypeService. It runs a Redis async job and it's under /grails-app/jobs folder.

All I want is to make sure that whenever I invoke this job#perform() method (which return type is void), a given dependent method called UpdateService#completeClaiming is invoked, but UpdateService#requestNewPin is not. (Listing is a domain class, by the way).

When I run this Spec, I keep getting an error message saying: "No more calls to 'completeClaiming' expected at this point. End of demands."

What am I doing wrong here? Any wild guesses?

```
@Mock(Listing)
class SubmissionJobSpec extends Specification {

def directoryTypeServiceMock
def updateServiceMock
def job

def setup(){
    job = new SubmissionJob()
    directoryTypeServiceMock = mockFor(DirectoryTypeService)
    updateServiceMock = mockFor(UpdateService)

    job.updateService = updateServiceMock.createMock()
    job.directoryTypeService = directoryTypeServiceMock.createMock()
}


def "if the directory is enabled and the pin status is ENTERED, we should call updateService.completeClaiming"() {
    given:
    directoryTypeServiceMock.demand.isUpdateEnabled { DirectoryType d, Country c -> return true}

    new Listing(
            location: new Location(country: Country.DE)
    ).save(failOnError: true, validate: false)

    when:
    job.perform(Listing.last().id, true)

    then:
    1 * updateServiceMock.completeClaiming(Listing.last(), true) >> new ListingEvent(output: [success: true])
    0 * updateServiceMock.requestNewPin(_ as Listing, true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing Groovy and Spock mocks. You can't use Spock mocking syntax (e.g. `0 * updateServiceMock.requestNewPin(_ as Listing, true)`) for a Groovy mock created with `mockFor()`. Spock mocks are created using `Mock()`, `Stub()` or `Spy()`. I'm not aware of any good reason to use a Groovy mock in a Spock spec.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. You're right, I was confused with both. But then, is there a way, using Grails mocks, to check how many times a collaborator method was executed, like in the example with 0 * updateServiceMock.requestNewPin(_ as Listing, true) ?

Comment: @felipecao One of the main features of Spock is interaction testing. It's a primary reason to use the library in the first place. Use Spock mocks instead and you'll be able to test your interactions. Grails mocks don't support it natively.